# how to get Horizontal and Vertical Scrollable list in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-listview

i am developing an android app where i am showing day wise channel schedule (multiple rows).
now in this i have to provide both vertical and horizontal scrollability.
vertical scrollability  will be normal , but horizontal scrollability should be synchronized
that is when user scrolls horizontally all other rows should also be scrolled in a sync.

i tried using table layout but its not going good with my requirement and i have also tried TwoWayView but i am not able to sync the horizontal scrolling.

i would like to know i anyone have faced/solved the similar situation.

Any leads on this is highly appreciated.

xml for vertical and horizontal Scrolling :-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/vertical_scroll_view2">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="910dp"
        android:id="@+id/scheduleContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</ScrollView>
```

.....
xml for TwoWayView:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weekday"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.mobiotics.tvb_stb.utilityclasses.TwoWayView

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/hlist"
        style="@style/TwoWayView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/weekday"
        android:scrollbars="none"

        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        tools:context="com.mobiotics.tvb_stb.activity.HomeScreenActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i am adding twoway list to linear layout .

Comment: i have added the xmls but i dont think it will be of any use .. these are latest xml file i am using .. before that i was using tablelayout in place of linearlayout and added rows at runtime !!

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a ListView, I would start there.  Just drop the ListView into a HorizontalScrollView.  Make sure to set the width of the HorizontalScrollView to wrap_content.  I noticed you have it set to fill_parent.